# Commit apenas no final das fases do cadastro

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, commit

Quero fazer um cadastro que terá diversas fazes, por exemplo: 1º cadastrarei informações básicas, ao avançar cadastrarei informações mais avançadas de acordo com o que foi passado na 1ª fase do cadastro e ao avançar novamente finalizarei o cadastro com algumas informações complementares.

Quero commitar isso tudo apenas no final do cadastro, como posso "segurar" os primeiros dados até o final do cadastro?

Alguém pode me dar uma dica de como fazer isso? Ainda que seja de alguma outra forma.

Estou usando Laravel 5.1 e postgresql

Comment: eu pensaria em ou usar a sessão ou usar uma tabela temporária no banco.

Comment: Você pode armazenar os dados via Cookies e depois mandar tudo de uma vez para o backend. Tem também alguns plugins para jquery que você faz um Step para cadastro.

Comment: Blz, vou dar uma pesquisada nessas formas então.